# Spring: multipart form upload parameter conversion not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Here my controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/files")
@Slf4j
public class FileUploadController {

  @PostMapping("/upload")
  public String handleFileUpload(
    @RequestParam("query") QueryForm form,
    @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
  throws IOException {
    log.info(form.toString());
    log.info(file.getOriginalFilename());
    log.info(file.getResource().getFilename());

    log.info(form.getQuery());

    return "upload";
  }

}
```

My QueryForm class:

```java
@Data
public class QueryForm {
    private String query;
    private int page;
    private int pageSize;
    private String sortField;
    private String sortDirection;
}
```

I'm trying to reach my endpoint using this `httpie` command:

```
http -f POST localhost:8080/api/files/upload file@1mb.txt query='{query:"example",page:1}'
```

I've also tried with:

```
http -f POST localhost:8080/api/files/upload file@1mb.txt query='{"query":"example","page":1}'
```

I'm getting this exception message on spring service:

> 023-04-18 12:59:43.478  WARN 28518 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'slab.tsystems.multipart.commonsupload.controller.QueryForm'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'slab.tsystems.multipart.commonsupload.controller.QueryForm': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]

Comment: query seems to be not in right format this should be in proper json so that it will be converted to POJO.
query:='{"query":"example","page":1}'

Comment: I also tried your approach. Exception raises.

Comment: Did you try to remove -f and write Content-Type:multipart/form-data after link?

Comment: is it resolved , if possible share git repo?